# How to run multiple instances of Emacs with a different icon attached to each one of them?

Tags: install

It could be a solution for Plasma or Gnome Shell or Xfce or even a windows manager like i3 or bspwm. I am interested in the mechanism of how to do it - so any solution will suffice.

For example, I want the first instance to have the standard icon, the second a different icon and the third a different icon.

Comment: maybe you need to configure your window manager (or desktop environment) to change icons depending on X11-window (emacs-frame) names. Note: X11-windows are named `Frames` in emacs docs. More Info: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame-Titles.html

Comment: I think this is a window manager configuration issue. This is definitely possible with a decent window manager. `fvwm2` could do this.